# Is there a better/faster way to implement multiple if statements like this?

Tags: python, discord.py

I made my Discord bot read text messages and respond to certain words, either with text or pictures. Since I'll probably make it react to a lot of words I wondered if there is a better way to implement multiple if statements like this:

```
@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        print(message.author.id, message.author)
        if client.user.id != message.author.id:
            if 'foo' in message.content:
                await message.channel.send('bar')
            if 'hello' in message.content:
                await message.channel.send('hey')
            if 'cat' in message.content:
                await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('cat.png'))
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If `message.content` contains "foo hello", do you want it to send both `bar` and `hey`? If not, then the second and third conditionals should be `elif` instead (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) so that only a max of one conditional gets evaluated as true. But a better way might be to to create a dictionary with the `key` as the word to look for, and the `value` as the response. Then for each message you would iterate over the dictionary to determine if there are any matching words/phrases found, and if so send that response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my opinion, it is ok.

You can also use a dictionary for such things. Something like this:

```
reactions_dict={'foo': 'bar',
                'hello': 'hey',
                'cat': discord.File('cat.png')}
for k,v in reactions_dict.items():
    if k in message.content:
        message.channel.send(v)
```

But I'm not here to say that this is the best choice in any situation. It's depends on the logic and complexity of the conditions.

PS:
In addition, in python 3.10, there will be a "case" and "match" syntax"
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/

Comment: Let's suppose I'll make cases for hundreds of words, are dictionaries the fastest way?

Comment: hundreds are small enough that you don't have to worry about the effectiveness of  dictionaries. In fact, the access complexity for python dict is `O(1)`, so it's not a problem anyway. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: discord.File('cat.png') won't send a picture but "<discord.file.File object at 0x7615f6f0>" because of the missing 'file=' upfront. Is there a way to fix this for dictionaries?

Comment: `'cat': file=discord.File('cat.png')` causes a syntax error

Comment: You can store arguments in dict too. Like this 
https://sharetext.me/dfw5rv1oms

Answer (score 1):

You can use lists like this

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author.id, message.author)
    if client.user.id != message.author.id:
        msg = ['foo', 'hello', 'cat']
        res = ['bar', 'hey', discord.File('cat.png')]
        if message.content in msg:
            a = msg.index(message.content)
            await message.channel.send(res[a])
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Or you could simply use a dict

Comment: Indeed but was already recommended and when I first started dictionaries were more complicated for me